# How to use a command output as for loop condition in bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop, conditional-statements

I wrote a for loop to work while a PID is running:

```
for (( j=0; (j < 40) && `kill -0 $pid` ; j++ )); do
  printf "."
  sleep 1
done
```

But it does not work and shows following error:

```
line 98: ((: (j < 40) &&  : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "&&  ")
```

I tried other options such as:

```
for (( j=0; (j < 40) && (kill -0 $pid) ; j++ )); do
for (( j=0; ((j < 40)) && ((kill -0 $pid)) ; j++ )); do
for (( j=0; ( ((j < 40)) && ((kill -0 $pid)) ) ; j++ )); do
for (( j=0; [ ((j < 40)) && ((kill -0 $pid)) ] ; j++ )); do
for (( j=0; ((j < 40)) && [kill -0 $pid] ; j++ )); do
```

But all of above variations cause some errors.

Comment: What is the purpose of using `kill` command in `for` loop?

Comment: @anubhava `'kill -0` will check if the process with given PID is running or not!

Comment: well if this for loop executes it will not cause your code to run as you have placed a <code>;</code>at the end

Comment: @PHP Learner, That doesn't answer the question anubhava asked.

Comment: @PHP Learner, Have you read what it says under [3.2.4.1 Looping Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs) "An alternate form of the for command is also supported: `for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) ; do commands ; done`?  I'm not the best at this but I take it that your usage "`(( j=0; (j < 40) && \`kill -0 $pid\` ; j++ ))`" is outside its scope and why you're getting the error you are.

Comment: @anubhava; @user3439894 I need the for loop works while the process is running and stops if the process finished. I used that kill command to check if the process is running or not.

Comment: @user3439894 I used `(j <40) && \`kill -0 $pid\`` as `expr2`

Comment: Keep loop simple as `for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do ... done`  and inside the loop check for return value of `kill`

Comment: @PHP Learner, As I said, I'm not the best at this, however I do not believe that "`(j < 40) && \`kill -0 $pid\``" in this context is a valid arithmetic expression.  That's my take on what is says in the Bash Reference Manual section I linked in my previous comment. I could be wrong.

Comment: @user3439894 Yes, you are right, none of the syntaxes I used is correct. I am looking for correct syntax for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use command substitution with ` inside of the arithmetic evaluation context of `((...))`.  It is probably easiest to rewrite this as a `while` loop.

```
tries=0
while kill -0 $pid; do
  (( tries++ > 40 )) && break
  printf "."
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: You used `kill -0` as `while` loop condition,is there any way to use it as `for` loop condition?